# RegEx for match at any part of line

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am searching through a large codebase in Eclipse, using its RegEx search functionality.  I need to find `<script>` tags that do not have a `src` attribute.  I am new to RegEx, but have been able to hack something together:

```
^.*(^<script(?!.*src).*)$
```

This matches the tags I am looking for, but only if there is nothing on the line before the `<script>` tag.  If there are spaces or anything, it doesn't match.

**Matches Correctly:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

**Does Not Match:**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
```

How can I modify my expression so that it matches in any part of the line?

I've also tried prepending `^`, `\s*`, `[ ]*`, and `(?x)` with no success.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question completely, but have you tried just `(<script(?!.*src).*)`?

Comment: Just ^.*(<script(?!.*src).*)$

Comment: @Luca, That works great!  Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe way would be to use regex pattern `(<script\b(?![^>]*\bsrc=)[^>]*>)`

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain why this is a better method than what @Luca posted?

Comment: @Brad - Consider input like `'text <script>alert("Hallo");</script> text <script src="url here"></script> text'`. Luca's regex will not find any match, because there is `src` ahead, which belongs to second `script` tag. See demo at ideone.com/kohwm

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but can probably simplify it to `<script(?!.*src.*)>`.

You aren't really interested in the beginning or end of line, so no need to include those aspects.

Incidentally, it was that second `^` that was throwing you off.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Unfortunately, this didn't match all of the tags I was looking for.  @Luca's answer of `^.*(<script(?!.*src).*)$` did work just fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use  `^.*(<script(?!.*src).*)$`